# How do you collect all the crew types?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

I'm trying for the achievement that unlocks the Kestrel's second layout. Is there a good way to collect all the unique aliens for the crew?

I've gotten close, but it's been entirely random.  Sometimes I find a store that allows you to recruit some.  Other times encounters have given me alien crew.

Are there certain encounters that are more likely to provide crew if you select the right option?  Are certain sectors more likely to provide you with specific crew types?

Comment: the hardest for me to find are the slugs usually, I've only gotten them twice in all my playthroughs

Comment: @yx.: If "six unique aliens" means one of each species, the hardest to find is going to be the "secret" one.

Comment: @JoeWreschnig, I got this achievement *without* the "secret" race crewmember - just the standard ones (human, engi, zoltan, rock, slug, mantis)

Comment: @agent86: Do you happen to know if you can get it with just six aliens of any race? (I've never had a full crew with only two humans, so I have no idea.)

Comment: @JoeWreschnig I've actually found the 'secret' one more often than the slug, so I still maintain the slug being the hardest :P

Comment: Yeah me too, I've had every species save slugs.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got this achievement yesterday, and the difficulty is that it is relatively random.  However, I'll share my anecdotal advice.

First, hit all the shops you can.  Shops don't always have crew, but there's a chance that they might.  I've found that shops in a sector belonging to a particular race tend to have that race more often, but it's random - sometimes I've been in Engi space and seen a shop full of Zoltans, for instance.  Crewmembers tend to cost less than 100 scrap, but I'd suggest trying to have ~100-150 scrap on hand just in case you find a shop that's got 2 races you need.

One event that I believe is more common in "pirate" and "civilian" sectors is an encounter with a slaver.  They may attempt to extort you to give them either some scrap or one of your crew members.  If you fight instead, they may later attempt to surrender by offering you a crew member.

From time to time when fighting a ship and killing its crew, I've been told it was a prisoner transport ship and that one of the prisoners wanted to join me.  I'd suggest attempting to take ships intact for this reason.  I haven't seen any indications in the initial system event that would indicate whether a ship is likely to give a crewmember if taken intact, though.

There are also events where you find a lone survivor on a deserted station, and this can sometimes provide you with an additional crewmember.  However, there's also a chance that they will go crazy and murder one of your existing crew, so this is not always a reliable way to make progress towards this achievement.  Commenters have noted that having a level 2 medbay can counter this, as can a slug crewmember.

Comment: I've found that having an advanced medbay can help with the 'going crazy' part with the lone survivor.  Or maybe it was a different event that I came across.

Comment: A level 2 med bay will stop them from going crazy. A slug crew member raises the chance of them being sane and also stops them from doing damage if they are crazy, but an acquired-by-slug madman will always be human.

Comment: Zoltan are the allies of Engi, so it makes sense for them to be for hire in Engi space.

Comment: One distress beacon in slug space can net you a slug. The introduction tells you how many moons there are. On the next page, the slug crew member asks how many moons there are. Get it right, get the slug. Get it wrong, he steals stuff from you and calls you an idiot. Pay attention!

Comment: If you didn't pay attention - there's always either seven or eleven moons, never five or six.

Answer (score 9):

To be honest, I found the other two a *lot* easier to get (All Installs is challenging on Normal, but trivial on Easy, and Tough Little Ship was actually quite fun to get), and then discovered that

> The alt form comes with 3 different species, which means you only need to find an Engi, a Rock (easy) and a Slug(slightly more challenging), and *you can get the achievement with that ship*

It's a bit of a cheat, but considering that the other two are relatively easy to get, I'd recommend going for them instead.

If you are dead set on getting this one using the Kestrel, then you need to focus on capturing over killing, so basically **Transporters**, **Boarding Drones**, **Bomb and Fire Weapons**, and **Sensors**. Spot 'em, blast and burn them, and then beam over for the coup.

You also want to focus on aiming for the right sectors.

- If you're missing Slugs, aim for the Nebulas
- If you're missing Rocks/Mantises, aim for the Red Zones
- If you're missing Engi & Zoltan, aim for the Green Zones