# How do I complete 'The United Federation'?

Tags: achievements, ftl-faster-than-light

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you collect all the crew types?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84603/how-do-you-collect-all-the-crew-types)

One of the Kestrel achievements 'The United Federation' mentions having a member of 6 different species on your ship at the same time.

What species are available to do this, and is there any easy way to find them? Is there any species that isn't apparently obvious that will help me complete this acheivment?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am assuming that you mean 'Kestrel' rather than Kessler - and by achievement you mean 'The United Federation'.

The text for the achievement says:

> Have six unique aliens on the Kestrel Cruiser simultaneously

This achievement requires that you have six different species on board at a specific point in time. There are a total of seven species in game, including the 'Crystal' species. These are:

- Crystal
- Engi
- Humans
- Mantis
- Rockmen
- Slugs
- Zoltan

With this in mind - no you *don't* need a member of the 'Crystal' species on board, you simply need six different species which can include a member of the 'Crystal' species if you happen to come across one before finding one of the other, easier to find, species.

Comment: edit your answer to include a list of the available species and hopefully everyone will be happy